# (VBA) Importing Data from Unique HTML File into Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba

I want to create a VBA code that pulls the relevant data I want to work with out of a webpage and posts it into HTML. I did a lot of searching, and I couldn't find a thread that was similar to my situation (I don't know much about HTML).

Here is the basic structure of the HTML file:

```html
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
<title>"title: abcdefg"</title>

</head>
<h1>"heading: 2345"</h1>
<p>
Last Updated: "Last date"
</p><p>

</p><p>
<next></next><table border="3" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="3">
<tbody><tr>
<td>
<pre>
*Want this data*

</pre>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<pre>
*Want this data*

</pre>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<pre>
*Want this data*
```

Note: The relevant data I want is in the locations of "*Want this data.* I got rid of it for confidentiality, but it seems the data is posted in some preformatted table, and I need to navigate to these points of the HTML and extract this data. The file continues in this form, I only posted the first 3 tables that I needed. Each table has data for a different day, and I want to extract every table on the webpage.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Traversing XML documents: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx   --- Basically add a reference to MSXML and use that to select nodes (i.e. <td></td> is a node)

Comment: Andrew: I used record macro and got the data by "get data from webpage." That seemed to work just fine. It gave me the relevant table I needed to get (which is the table that includes all the tables of data within). But I am still wondering if there is a way to code for this as soon as you get to the webpage.