# VBA: Using Control F and Grabbing Relevant Data from IE Webpage

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, dom, web-scraping

Goal: Make a VBA Macro that opens up a webpage via IE, loops through entire page, uses the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> function to find MULTIPLE keywords, if those keywords are found, locates the row those keywords are in, and grabs a certain number of rows above and below that keyword row location and posts them to an excel sheet to be emailed out.

I have code that goes to the webpage, and uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find the keyword. This part works correctly. I don't know how to loop through the whole webpage and do this for multiple keywords. I also am having trouble finding the row location of each keyword 'hit' and posting it to excel  (not that skilled with VBA).

```
Sub Find()

    'create a variable to refer to an IE application, and
    'start up a new copy of IE
    Dim ieApp As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim objectIE As Object

    'make sure you can see
    ieApp.Visible = True

    'go to the website of interest
    ieApp.Navigate "URL HERE"

    'wait for page to finish loading
    Do While ieApp.Busy
    Loop

    'Declare Keywords
    Dim keyword1 As String
    Dim found As Boolean

    keyword1 = "keyword"
    For i = 1 To ie.document.all.Length
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        SendKeys "^f"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        SendKeys (keyword1)
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please provide any URL, keyword and expected output for example?

Comment: If I may, if you have to do searches over the webpage only, why not open it directly in excel instead of looping in the IE object?

Comment: Is there a find command i can use if I do it this way? the underlying code is html, and I made a code that parses the data and breaks it up, but the formatting gets altered (spaces between characters changes) when I do this to bring it into excel, and it becomes hard to scan for keywords

Comment: When you retrieve a web page with an Internet.Explorer object, you are retrieving the HTML behind it. It makes more sense to use something even as rudimentary as the [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1.aspx)  on the base HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example, which implements keyword look up in webpage document text nodes, if found - expands the range to the entire table cell, then outputs all matches on to worksheet:

```vb
Sub Find()

    sKeyword = "language"
    sUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/tags"

    Set oList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

        .Visible = True
        ' Navigating to url
        .Navigate sUrl
        ' Wait for IE ready
        Do While .ReadyState <> 4 Or .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
        ' Wait for document complete
        Do While .Document.ReadyState <> "complete"
            DoEvents
        Loop

        '    ' Look up in the specified node - optional
        '    ' Wait for target node created
        '    Do While TypeName(.Document.getElementById("Content")) = "Null" ' replace Content with your Id
        '        DoEvents
        '    Loop
        '    ' Get target node
        '    Set oRoot = .Document.getElementById("Content")

        ' Look up in the entire document
        Set oRoot = .Document.getElementsByTagName("html")(0)
        Set oWalker = .Document.createTreeWalker(oRoot, 4, Null, False) ' NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT = 4
        Set oNode = oWalker.currentNode
        Do
            Select Case True
                Case IsNull(oNode.NodeValue)
                Case oNode.NodeValue = ""
                Case InStr(oNode.NodeValue, sKeyword) = 0
                Case Else
                    ' Text node contains keyword
                    Debug.Print oNode.NodeValue
                    Do
                        ' Expand the range until thenode of the necessary type is enclosed
                        Set oNode = oNode.ParentNode
                        Debug.Print TypeName(oNode)
                        Select Case TypeName(oNode)
                            '   ' Non-table structures
                            '   Case "HTMLHtmlElement", "HTMLBody", "HTMLDivElement", "HTMLParagraphElement", "HTMLHeadingElement"
                            ' For tables
                            Case "HTMLHtmlElement", "HTMLBody", "HTMLTableRow", "HTMLTableCell"
                                Exit Do
                        End Select
                    Loop
                    ' Add to list
                    sText = oNode.innerText
                    Debug.Print sText
                    oList(oList.Count) = sText
            End Select
            ' Get next node
            oWalker.NextNode
            Set oPrev = oNode
            Set oNode = oWalker.currentNode
        Loop Until oNode Is oPrev
        .Quit

    End With

    ' Results output
    aList = oList.Items()
    Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(aList) + 1, 1).Value = aList

End Sub
```

As an example, for source page as follows

[image: src]

the output is

[image: output]

For multiple keywords search please elaborate the rule: do all keywords, or at least one of the keywords should be found in one sentence?

Comment: Thank you so much! I think it is also worth mentioning that the underlying script of the IE webpage is HTML, with the keywords I want to search for inside tables that are split up into various cells based on the HTML code. I ran this code and it didn't work. I get a 438 error: object doesn't support this property or method for the line: Set oWalker = .Document.createTreeWalker(oRoot, 4, Null, False) ' NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT = 4

Comment: The underlying HTML CODE:

</p><p>
<next></next><table border="3" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="3">
<tbody><tr>
<td>
<pre>
*Looking for keyword here*

</pre>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<pre>
*Looking for keyword here*

Comment: @A.Cod `createTreeWalker` is supported since IE 9, what IE version do you use? Also don't confuse a _script_, which is procedural language at bottom, and a _HT**ML**_, which is **M**arkup **L**anguage. So it's not quite clear for me how "the script can be HTML".

Comment: gotchya, I'll stop saying that. Just meant to say the page is made up of HTML. But I am using IE 11!

So would your code still work for this instant? The keyword I am looking for is within <tr> </tr> of the html tags. This code (based on what you searched, and the output) looks like exactly what I want. I am having trouble manipulating it for my case

Comment: @A.Cod Do you get 438 error running my code, quite as above? Or you have made any changes to it?

Comment: I get 438 error after i copied and pasted your code into my macro, and changed the URL and keyword. When I used your url and keyword the code works. Is this because the webpage I want is underlying HTML?

Comment: @A.Cod Generally any webpage is written in HTML. For insight could you please specify more details? What is URL you tried? When the error occurs press _Debug_ and type into _Immediate_ window: `? oList.Count`, press Enter, and `? Join(oList.Items(), vbCrLf)`, Enter - what output does it return?

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I can't post the URL since it is an intranet site and you need a login to get into the relevant page I want. But if you go to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821308/vba-importing-data-from-unique-html-file-into-excel), the format of the webpage is shown in HTML. And when i put oList.Count in the immediate window I get 0, when i do Join(oList.Items(), vbCrLf), there is no response.

Comment: @A.Cod I've taken a look at that webpage content, seems my code didn't work because of `<body>` node missing. I've slightly changed the code, check if it works now.

Comment: I used the new code, and still getting the same error at the same part. olist.count still returns 0, and join(olist.items, vbcrlf) still has no output. What do you think it is? The types of keywords I am looking for aren't real words (egt margin, ntb, n1, etc.), i dont know if that changes anything but thought i'd tell you. Also, each div of the html is filled with multiple lines of data, not just one line